# Objective-C for microcontrollers?

Tags: objective-c, microcontroller, stm32

I want to know if it is possible to program a STM32 microcontroller using Objective-C. Are there any IDE's with tools to compile directly from Objective-C to machine code?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

STM32 is ARM. GCC can compile Objective-C to ARM machine code. The real question is whether or not that's useful in the absence of an Objective-C runtime and Foundation frameworks. From [this wiki page](http://wiki.gnustep.org/index.php/Platform%3aOther) it looks like there has been some effort to get GNUStep building for various ARM targets. Perhaps that'd be a good place to start.

Comment: Thanks for the info! I guess I'm trying to find an already built-in solution, I don't want to get my hands dirty by manually setting up compilers and stuff.

Comment: You're probably out of luck, then.